# Интерфейс Unity пропадает и исчезает во время работы

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

Веду работу в unity 2022.3.10f1 
В прошлом году работал в unity, все было хорошо, тогда компьютер был даже слабее, чем сейчас.
Там был старый процессор intel core i7 6го поколения или 7го.
Все работало хорошо, иногда лагало, но это спокойно можно было списать на слабость процессора и его возраст.

Однако сейчас вернулся в юнити. Столкнулся с проблемой, что сейчас интерфейс самого движка лагает, провисает и исчезает.
Комп сильный:
intel core i9 12900-RF
GeForce GTX 1660 ROG STRIX GAMING 6GB
32 gb оперативки 3200.
ssd m2 на 7200 чтения и 700 записи

Итак, проблема в отображении самого интерфейса. Например:
Я хочу уменьшить размер блока Hierarchy, увеличив тем самым размер окна с симулятором или сценой, в этот момент у меня просто Hierarchy становится черной и в ней ничего не видно. Тоже самое происходит в других элементах.
Когда я пытаюсь добавить в animator Behavior, то у меня весь экран аниматора становится черным и никак не реагирует на мышку.
Так же у меня в scene просто не отображается UI интерфейс, его просто напросто никак не видно.
Симулятор (запуск теста) работает через раз, не всегда отображая изменения проекта, даже если они сохранены.

**Пример черного экрана с Hierarchy**

*Работает*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Исчезает*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пример с отображением на сцене**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю, как решать данную проблему. Переустановка всего unity не помогла, а переустанавливать Windows я в данный период времени никак не могу.